# Why display:flex can not print properly in HTML?

Tags: html, css, printing, flexbox

I have developed a stock tracking app for my customers. This app also can generate barcode. I would like to allow print barcodes in printer, but I cannot do it properly. In a page, there have to be 72 barcodes that are ordered by CSS display:flex. Everything ok in my screen. But in print screen there is something wrong. I need help about this topic. I have done some triements as remove flex codes or decrease column about by decrease barcode numbers, it is ok again in printing.

CSS codes:

```
                body {
            background: rgb(204, 204, 204);
        }

        page {
            background: white;
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
            margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
            box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        }

        page[size="A4"] {
            width: 21cm;
            height: 29.7cm;
        }

        page[size="A4"][layout="landscape"] {
            width: 29.7cm;
            height: 21cm;
        }

        

        .tablo {
            position: absolute;
            margin-top: 1.05cm;
            margin-left: 0cm;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;


        }


        .hucre {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;

            border: 1px solid black;
            width: 35mm;
            height: 23mm;
            padding-left: 0.11cm;
            padding-right: 0.11cm;
            padding-top: 0.065cm
        }

        .firm {
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 0.7;
            font-size: 0.7rem;
            font-weight: 600;
        }

        .barkod {
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 0.7;
            font-size: 0.7rem;
        }

        svg {
            height: 16mm;
        }


        @media print {

            body,
            page {
                margin: 0;
                box-shadow: 0;

            }
        }
```

HTML codes:

```
    <page size="A4">
        <div style="position:absolute; margin-top:3mm; margin-left:3mm">
            <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="hoverEffect me-2" onclick="history.back()"><i class="bi bi-arrow-left-circle"></i> GERİ
                </div>
                <div class="hoverEffect" onclick="window.print()"><i class="bi bi-printer"></i> YAZDIR</div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="tablo" id="tablo">


        </div>


    </page>
```

Problem visuals:

[Everything is ok in website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hda37.jpg)

[Right and bottom (not shown) gaps appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdCWT.jpg)

Try to solve my problem

Comment: `.hure {flex-shrink:0;flex-grow:1;}` ? unsure because we're missing: the html code

Comment: I'd like to help but I don't really understand the problem. Is the problem that there is some white space left to the right?

Answer (score 0):

actually, error not in your html or css code.
you have to choose right print option.

i think you want to take a pdf print or something like that.
so you must go to your print ( page / scale ) option.

you can look this images for advanced print settings.
( "none" margin. )

[image]